# Масштабируемые JavaScript приложения

Tags: javascript

Речь идет о такого плана вещах. 
[habrahabr.ru](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/javascript/123635/)

В пример даю именно эту статью поскольку она одна из самых вменяемых которые успел нарыть.

Очень буду благодарен всем кто что-то посоветует из собственного опыта. Действительно столкнулся с проблемой разработки сложного пользовательского интерфейса. Интересует способ с применением jQuery поскольку некоторые библиотеки уже утверждены, и без поворотно. Прошу не давать советов плана нафиг это тебе надо, фигня и так дальше. Получается реально каша с которой очень трудно бороться. Есть уже опыт более простого проекта, окна, перетаскивание и.т.д. Все делалось в лоб, вешались обработчики на айди, или чилды. Работает, но желания туда лазить нету вообще. И местами уже сам не понимаю как оно работает. Чтобы не ставать на эти грабли начал лазить по исходникам Jquery UI и kendo ui. Ну они молодцы, что тут сказать. Такого как айди вобще нету, и двигаются от выбранного елемента в низ, и.т.д. Таким образом манипулируя ним. Это все круто, и умно. Но все это когда начинаеш связывать, и пытаешся заставить все это взаимодействовать между собой, то фигня еще та.

За ранее спасибо за любые советы в этом плане.

Comment: Не совсем понял вопроса в целом, а по поводу приведенной статьи я на 100% согласен с этими словами:

у вас абстракции лишь увеличивают сложность системы, вместо того, чтобы её уменьшать. яваскрипт, который парсится яваскриптом, чтобы сформировать яваскрипт, который формирует хтмл с инлайновым яваскриптом собственный примитивный язык запросов с яваскриптовыми вставками, для которого даже подсветки синтаксиса нигде нет ...

Comment: Из всего прочитаного в статье реально более менее полезным был последний комментарий о **require.js** ^.^

Вообщем лично меня привели в тихий ужас те страшные пляски с бубном описанные в статье. Как всегда религиозный холивар ниачем в комментариях, вообщем все как обычно :)

Т.к. я знаю и истинно верю в то что "все гениальное просто", твердо убежден - описаная там идея от лукавого :)

Comment: Вопрос надо было отметить - **danger holywar** ^.^

Comment: Ребята, это далико не холивар. Если на странице появляются и исчезают элементы, и у каждого свои цели, то избежать трудностей очень трудно. Каеладки везде. Особенно проблемно отследить все обработчики которые вешаются и не удаляются.

Comment: Что-бы что-то было масштабируемо, нужно писать соответствующе

ИМХО: jQuery( сам по себе, без плагинов ) - это плохой инструмент для такой цели. Абстракция - практически 0... Первое что надо сделать - отказаться от работы с DOM напрямую, и сразу будет намного легче

Comment: По-моему тоже  - jquery не катит для таких целей.

Как мне кажется - тут нужно что-то типа prototype.js

Ну тут опять таки - не вижу смысла отказыватся от работы с домом на прямую если это не есть что-то реально большое ( в плане клента ), если же большое - тогда да, солидарен на 100%

Answer (score 1):

я бы посоветовал использовать что-то наподобие backbone.js 
сам пишу на нем - фреймворк структурирует код своим ооп.

Answer (score 1):

knockoutjs в качестве альтернативы backbone.js